# Prevent object modification inside Dictionary

Tags: c#, reference, datatable

I am using the following c# code:

```
DataTable table = GetDataTable();
Dictionary<int, DataTable> d = new Dictionary<int, DataTable>();
d.Add(1, table);
table = modifyTable(table);

//Do some operations on d[1]
```

Here when I am changing the table, the table inside dictionary(`d[1]`) is getting changed. How can I prevent modification of table in Dictionary? Why is this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I prevent modification of table in Dictionary?

Pass a copy of your DataTable. It's easy to create with [DataTable.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
DataTable table = GetDataTable();
Dictionary<int, DataTable> d = new Dictionary<int, DataTable>();
d.Add(1, table.Copy());
```

> Why is this behavior?

You are passing reference to DataTable, because DataTable is a reference type. Thus you have two references pointing to one DataTable instance. So when you do operations with reference returned by `d[1]` you are modifying same object which is referenced by `table` reference.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The table inside dictionary is just a reference of your table that you add. 
If you don't want to modify the table inside dictionary you should add a copy of it.